# There is not text in the items of my recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am creating a project based on the recyclerview. I have created a Adapter class within which is the ViewHolder and I have also created the Model Class named as ListItems. After doing everything else when I tried to run the app it is showing all the cardViews but no text is displayed on to them. These are the codes in different classes and layout that I have.

This is the AdapterClass which I have named as homeCardAdapter

```
public class homeCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<homeCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ListItems> listItems;
private Context context;

public homeCardAdapter(List<ListItems> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardview_home, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItems listItem = listItems.get(position);
    holder.cardHead.setText(listItem.getTitle());
    holder.cardDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());
    holder.pay.setText(listItem.getPay());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView cardHead, cardDesc, pay;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardHead = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyName);
        cardDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardDescription);
        pay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pay);
    }
}
}
```

This is the code of my Model class named as ListItems

```
public class ListItems {
String title, description, pay;

public ListItems(String title, String description, String pay) {
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getPay() {
    return pay;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return description;
}

}
```

This is the Java Activity which I have named as Welcome

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Welcome";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private List<ListItems> listItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting");

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
        ListItems listItem = new ListItems(
                "Port Organization" + (i+1),
                "Lorem Ipsum The Description Will Go over Here So As for case" + (i),
                "250" + (i) + "/ Week"
        );
        listItems.add(listItem);
    }

    adapter = new homeCardAdapter(listItems,this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

This is the CardView which I am using in the RecyclerView

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:text="$450 / Week"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/companyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Company Name"
            android:layout_below="@id/pay"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardDescription"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum Some Text Goes Over Here"
            android:layout_below="@id/companyName"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Please suggest me edits so that I can get the texts to my cards.

Comment: you forgot to set values inside constructor.
Use this code.
public ListItems(String title, String description, String pay) {
this. title= title;
this. description= description;
this. pay= pay;
}

Comment: Yes but that values are not initialising in model class. check your model class

Comment: "*didn't work*" is not a sufficient description of an issue. Please elaborate and include any error stacktrace in your question. As it stands, your question shows an incorrectly written constructor which would cause the issue you're describing, so if using a correct constructor is *not working* for you, you need to say why and how.

Comment: post your cardview_home.xml.

Comment: `public class homeCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<homeCardAdapter.ViewHolder>` try change this to `public class homeCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`

Comment: It is working Arti Patel Thanks.

Comment: ohk Good. issue was in constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize values in your constructor, Use like this constructor

```
public ListItems(String title, String description, String pay) {
this.title = title;
this.description= description;
this.pay= pay;
}
```